# Maui TabbedRenderer (iOS) with custom property

Tags: maui, maui-ios

i have a custom TabbedPage with an additional property. Like this:

```c#
public class CustomTabbedPage : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TabbedPage {
        public static readonly BindableProperty SeparatorLineColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SeparatorLineColor),
           typeof(Color), typeof(CustomTabbedPage), null, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.Default);

        public Color SeparatorLineColor {
            set => SetValue(SeparatorLineColorProperty, value);
            get => (Color)GetValue(SeparatorLineColorProperty);
        }
}
```

In the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-8.0#page-handlers it is mentioned that TabbedPage handlers are TabbedRenderer in iOS and android. So i created in a partial class in iOS platform folder:

```c#
public partial class TabbedPageHandler : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.TabbedRenderer{
    private static void MapSeparatorLineColor(TabbedRenderer renderer, TabbedPage page) {
        //Test
    }
}
```

and in a partial class for the property mapper:

```c#
public partial class TabbedPageHandler {
        public static PropertyMapper<CustomTabbedPage, TabbedPageHandler> PropertyMapper = new PropertyMapper<CustomTabbedPage, TabbedPageHandler>(Mapper) {        
            [nameof(CustomTabbedPage.SeparatorLineColor)] = MapSeparatorLineColor,
        };
        public TabbedPageHandler() : base(PropertyMapper) { //Error
        }
}
```

The problem is, that the `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.TabbedRenderer` has no constructor for the mapped properties, but the static `Mapper` field exists in `TabbedRenderer`.

I tried to add my custom property in a static constructor:

```c#
    public partial class TabbedPageHandler {
        static TabbedPageHandler() {
            Mapper.Add(nameof(CustomTabbedPage.SeparatorLineColor), MapSeparatorLineColor);
        }



        //public static PropertyMapper<CustomTabbedPage, TabbedPageHandler> PropertyMapper = new PropertyMapper<CustomTabbedPage, TabbedPageHandler>(Mapper) {      
        //  [nameof(CustomTabbedPage.SeparatorLineColor)] = MapSeparatorLineColor,
        //};

        //public TabbedPageHandler() : base(PropertyMapper) {
        //}
    }
```

This works, but i have doubts this is the correct implementation. What is the correct way to map my custom property? I have expected that this works like entrys and the constructor from the base class takes my custom properties.

Comment: If you ask me I would say don't use maui's tabbed page, instead use Sharpnado or Uranuim's tab control they have better performance

Comment: There is no api exposed to change ```SeparatorLineColor``` for MAUI. You may raise a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

Comment: Or you may could try using a [Maui Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/?view=net-maui-8.0) and customize your own tabbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue is open at github: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19998. There is also a workaround. I think the MAUI-Team will fix it sometimes.